# Are 2d gauge anomalies determined by genus-one data?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, gauge-theory, condensed-matter

Let $G$ be a (finite, say) group and $\alpha \in \mathrm{H}^3(\mathrm{B}G; \mathrm{U}(1))$ a 3-cohomology class. For each oriented 3-manifold $X^3$ equipped with a $G$-bundle $P : X \to \mathrm{B}G$, one can pull back $\alpha$ and integrate: $\int_X P^*\alpha \in \mathrm{U}(1)$.

I would like to restrict attention just to genus-one mapping tori. By this I mean: given $\gamma \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, build the manifold $T(\gamma) = T^2 \times [0,1] /\sim$ where for $(x,y) \in T^2$, I set $((x,y),0) \sim (\gamma(x,y),1)$.

**Question:** Is the class $\alpha$ necessarily determined by the values of $\int_{T(\gamma)} P^*\alpha$ for all $\gamma \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ and $P : T(\gamma) \to \mathrm{B}G$?

Comment: Just curious...  What is an "anomaly"?  Perhaps I could ask that separately?

Comment: @johnmangual The context of my question is the following. Suppose you have a 2d (i.e. (1+1)d) QFT with a global $G$ symmetry. You can try to "gauge" that symmetry. If the QFT were trivial, then you'd be trying to write down a pure 2d $G$-gauge theory, i.e. a 2d Dijkgraaf--Witten theory. These are, of course, classified by classes in $H^2(BG; U(1))$. This class is the data of the "Lagrangian" for the gauge fields. If your QFT is nontrivial, then you already have some fields and Lagrangian for your QFT, and gauging the $G$ symmetry requires choosing an additional term in the Lagrangian for ...

Comment: ... the gauge fields. This additional term is something like a 2-cocycle on $BG$ modulo coboundaries. Actually, it isn't quite. It is a 2-cochain $\beta$ on $BG$ modulo coboundaries with prescribed derivative $d\beta = \alpha$. The 3-cocycle $\alpha$ is determined explicitly from the data of how $G$ acts on your QFT. So if $\alpha$ vanishes in cohomology, then you can find a $\beta$ and gauge the symmetry. If $\alpha$ is cohomologically nontrivial, then you cannot gauge the symmetry. The cohomology class $\alpha \in H^3(BG;U(1))$ is called the *anomaly* or *gauge anomaly* of the symmetry.

Comment: In examples, one only has partial information about a QFT. For example, one might know the behavior of the QFT on closed tori ("genus-one data") without knowing a fully-local description of the QFT. In particular, in the examples I care about, I know how to compute the numbers $\int_{T(\gamma)}P^*\alpha$, but I don't have a direct description of the anomaly $\alpha$. (I would have such a description if I had a fully local, $G$-symmetric description of the QFT.) Hence my question: is the anomaly determined by genus-one data?

Comment: BTW, Witten has a nice ten-page note at https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01791 describing some of this physics. The point is that a global action of $G$ on a 2d QFT is "the same" as a way of placing your QFT at the "boundary" of a 3d pure gauge theory with gauge group $G$. In this description, $\alpha$ is nothing but the action for that 3d pure gauge theory (= 3d Dijkgraaf--Witten theory). See also section 2 of my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08388 and I'm sure many other places.

Comment: It sounds like there's already a (independent) question here on the gauging of symmetries and their anomaly.   They are certainly pushing the vocabulary on what we call "symmetry". It's the symmetry the Lagrangian of your theory,  which lives on a $G$-bundle over a 3-manifold.

Comment: Hi @johnmangual, I don't quite understand your comment. The mathematical question I want to ask is whether the restrictions to genus-one, in the sense I gave, determines classes in $H^3(BG, U(1))$. My comments tried to outline why that question was summarized by my title. The relation between (anomalies for) symmetries of 2d QFTs are (actions for) 3d gauge theories is pretty well known, although I'm happy to try to explain it better. (E.g. my comments pretended that the 2d theory necessarily had a fields+Lagrangian description compatible with $G$, which isn't true in general.)

Comment: As to your notation, is this the integration along fibres in the Gysin sequence?

Comment: @user51223 Probably. I think of it as the line bundle on $M_{ell}(BG) = \{$moduli space of elliptic curves with $G$-bundle$\}$ whose fiber over $E$ is formed by pulling back of $\alpha$ along $ev: E \times maps(E,BG) \to BG$ and then integrating the $3$-class $\alpha$ along $E$ to get a $1$-class on $maps(E,BG)$. [I learned the construction of this line bundle in a paper of N. Ganter's. Sorry I can't find the paper right now.] Specifically, the values of $\int_{T(\gamma)}P^*\alpha$ are (all) the monodromies of this line bundle, since a loop in $M_{ell}(BG)$ is (some irrelevant geometric ...

Comment: ... data describing the choice of elliptic curve and) a mapping torus $T(\gamma)$ equipped with a $G$-bundle $P : T(\gamma) \to BG$. This is why I call these values the "genus one data" of the anomaly $\alpha$.

Comment: So you expect $\int P^*\alpha$ to live in $H^1(BG;U(1))$ ?!? Do you really mean $\int_{T(\gamma)}$? If $\int_{T(\gamma)}$ is meant here, can you fit it into a fibration over $BG$ ? I want to understand if this is compatible with the usual notation of writing $\int_F$ for the Gysin homomorphism associated to a fibre bundle $F\to E\to B$, or not you have some ambient space $X$ in which $T(\gamma)$ embeds for any $\gamma\in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ ?!?

Comment: @user51223 There is a line bundle, as I said, on the moduli space of 2-tori equipped with G-bundles. The line bundle is formed exactly as you said: the fiber at $(E,P)$ is $\int_E P^*\alpha$, where this $\int_E$ is the Gysin homomorphism. The *numbers* $\int_{T(\gamma)}P^*\alpha$ provide all the data of this line bundle.

Comment: I have now idea if this is related to the question, but there are groups which have more than one cohomology class for which the twisted double gives rise to the same modular data https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02796

Comment: @Marcel, indeed, I think you might have answered the question with a nice firm "no". I'll need to think slightly before I'm sure...

Comment: If the integral you wrote down is the Dijkgraaf-Witten invariant, and if the invariants of the manifolds you wrote down can be computed purely in terms of the S- and T-matrix, then this is indeed a no to your question.

Comment: @MarcelBischoff Yes, I had intended (one thing that goes under the name of) the DW invariant. I put the parenthetical because in (another thing that goes under the name of) the DW invariant, you sum over all G-bundles of the value I intended. So it includes the T-matrix itself, and not just, say, its trace. But I do think it depends only on the modular data of the twisted double, for appropriate definition of "modular data of the twisted double".